# is there any way to make sure that I am passing a component with certain props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

If I have a component that will have a prop value or children as other JSX functional components and I want to make sure that those components have certain props passed
[image]

so here I want to make sure if another developer used the component the inputs will have like `<Trail value=''/>`

Comment: Just make `value` prop required in `Trail`?

Comment: There is no way to specify that the given components need to have a specific prop.

Comment: @kinduser I want the component to make sure that the components passed to it have those props also

Comment: Why? Some reproduced problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PropTypes` for that. `PropTypes` is a library that let you specify what props your component will receive and if the props are required or not.

In your case, an example of `PropTypes` implementation would be:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function Trail(props) {
  return <span>{props.value}</span>;
}

Trail.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

And If `value` is not passed as props to your component, it would trigger a warning in the console.

Find more info about usage and Types at the [official React documentation on the topic](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and on the [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this question with TypeScript, I will answer accordingly.

You can define your props type. Then the TypeScript compiler will complain if the required props are not supplied.

```js
type Props = {
    value: string;
};

const Trail = ({ value }: Props) => {
    // Implementation
}
```

Alternatively you can use `interface` instead of `type`.

See this cheetsheet for more info: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/basic_type_example.